# Capybara/Selenium: Speeding up Dropdown Selecting?

Tags: selenium, capybara

So this is a bit of a performance question regarding Selenium Webdriver (Chromedriver) and Capybara.

I have some react-select dropdowns with quite a bit of data in them. For some reason the react-selects take a VERY VERY long time to pick out the option in them. The code is pretty simple and I grabbed it from here: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/832

But it basically comes down to:

```
page.find('.Select-control').click
page.find('.Select-option', text: 'the text').click
```

Thing is, this works fine. But it takes an extremely long time (Upwards of a minute a dropdown). Now...in Capybaras defense these dropdowns have a LOT of options to select from, so I thought selecting from the top-most item would be the fastest, but that doesn't seem to affect it.

Does Capybara/Selenium hold the "options" in a different sorted list somewhere or something? Since i'd assume selecting from a top option in the dropdown would be faster, but it doesn't seem to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, when using the `text` option, `find` first finds all the elements that match using the locator with the current selector type.  In your case your selector type is defaulting to :css, and the locator is `.Select-option`.  So Capybara will find all elements with the class `Select-option` and then it will go through each of those elements comparing the text to see what matches (and checking visibility), but it will have to compare all of them to make sure the selector isn't ambiguous.

One way to speed that up would be to use `first` with a `minimum` option

```
page.first('.Select-option', text: 'the text', minimum: 1).click
```

which can skip some of the text and visibility checking since it doesn't have to worry about ambiguous elements.  Another solution would be to skip the `text` option altogether and write it into an XPath along the lines of

```
page.find(:xpath, XPath.css('.Select-option')[XPath.string.n.is('the text')]).click # Haven't verified this is 100% correct but it should be close
```

If you're doing this a lot in your app you may want to consider creating a custom selector for this

```
Capybara.add_selector(:react_option) do
  xpath do |locator|
    XPath.css('.Select-option')[XPath.string.n.is(locator)]
  end
  # You can add other filters in here - see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector.rb
end
```

which would then allow you to do

```
page.find(:react_option, 'the text').click
```

Note, if you can limit the element types it will also make the query more efficient, so if all of the elements are `<li>` elements you might want to do something like

```
XPath.css('li.Select-option')[XPath.string.n.is(locator)]
```

Comment: Thanks, anything to speed it up will help so i'll give these a try. Isn't using Xpath brittle though? especially if the option ordering changes? Or would that not be affected here.

Comment: @msmith1114 It's not that XPath is brittle, it's that the way most new users of Capybara try to use it leads to brittle things.  They tend to copy the really long XPath produced by the browser and drop it in Capybara, which means if any little bit of page structure changes it is invalid for the element expected.  The XPaths this produces are only looking for specific classes on elements and the text in the element.  Generally XPath is harder to read than CSS, so the rule of thumb to stick with CSS when possible, however CSS doesn't have any text content matching ability while XPath does.

Comment: @msmith1114 Don't forget to accept the answer if this speeds things up for you.